# Probability theory: calculating the probability of a joint event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to determine the probability of a 'joint' event. The events are $A,B$ which are independent. $A$ is Binomial distributed with pmf $p_A(A)$ and $B$ is given by its cdf $P_B(B)$ and is also discrete. Now, I want to calculate the probability of the joined event

$P( A=i \cap B =i) = $

which of the following methods are correct?

i)$\left[ \sum_{l=0}^{m} \binom{m}{l} p_A^l (1-p_A)^{m-l} \right] * P_B(B=i)$

ii)$\sum_{l=0}^{m} \binom{m}{l} p_A^l (1-p_A)^{m-l}p_B(l) $

iii) none of these :-)

where $p_B(k) = P_B(k)-P_B(k-1)$ is the pmf of the discrete cdf $P_B(B)$.

i) uses $P_{A,B}(A=a \cap B=b) = P_A(A=a)  P_B(B=b)$

ii) uses the fact that $p_{A,B}(a,b) = p_A(a) p_B(b)$

Comment: Allow me to clarify the question, Bernoulli or Binomial distribution?

Comment: 1) Binomial distribution has a finite support. 2) otherwise your i) seems correct

Comment: Sorry, I meant Binomial distribution and correction the limits. @Alex, thanks for your answer. Can you clarify why (ii) is wrong?

Comment: hold on, what's you $P_{B}(B=k)$? Is it cdf or pdf?

Comment: @Alex, the cdf is denoted by $P_B$ and the pmf by $p_B$. So capitals cdf and lower case pmf.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize it. Why make things more complicated, you task is simple enough. Just take the product of two pmfs as the rvs are independent.

Comment: @Alex, but this would correspond to the (ii) approach right? Assuming that $p_B(l) =0$ for $l<0$.

Comment: This question seems to mix random variables and events, for example what exactly are A and B, the latter or the former?

Comment: @Did yes, you're right. I hope its now clearer after the edit.

Comment: "The events are A,B which are independent. A is Binomial distributed with pmf..." Hmmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ and $Y \sim F(\cdot)$ which is discrete, and these rvs are independent, then

$$
P(X=n \cap Y=n)=P(X=n)P(Y=n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \cdot P(Y=n)
$$
where the last term of course depends on the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you also show how this would look like when using the pdf/pmf of Y and whether the relationship I used for the pdf/pmf is correct?

Comment: btw. are you sure that the limits in your sum are correct? I mean because the $k$ is also used as an index.

Comment: thanks, corrected the typo. What od you know of pdf of $Y$?

Comment: Thanks again. I thought that if $Y$ is discrete and its cdf $P(Y)$ is known than its pdf is given by $p(k) = P(Y=k)-P(Y=k-1)$ as a discrete differentiation. Then, I could also use the pdf to compute the probability which may not be easier in this case but also possible, right?

Comment: No what you wrote doesn't mean anything, it may be even negative. What you probably mean is $P(Y=k)=P(Y \leq k)-P(Y \leq k-1)$.

Comment: Yes you're right, I mixed up the probability and the cdf by using the same symbol. Here, I actually meant the cdf with $P$. Totally confusing my notation. Thank you very much. But would it look like using the pdf?

Comment: just use the expression in my previous comment